# Quantlib binomial tree

Tags: quantlib, binomial-tree

I was trying to price options with the extendedBinomialTree class of quantlib. I actually tried at some point to modify this class in order to optimize it. Normally the drift and diffusion of the underlying asset are changing but i want to add new data members so that i won't have to compute them between two times if they remain constant between them.

Thank you in advance for your answers !